# Find OpenSCAD code from image

Tags: openscad

I have an OpenSCAD model which I am looking at in the application, code to the left and the rendering to the right.

Am trying to modify a certain piece, and have commented out all the commands that I believed were related to that piece, but there is still one subtracted cube left, i.e. somewhere in the code there is a `difference` block with this `cube` command somewhere in the 2nd part (I believe, as I cannot see any other possibility).

It would be very nice if I could just click on the image and get the software to display the corresponding commands in the code.

Is anything like that available in any tool?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, OpenSCAD does not have any such feature. However, a related feature might help you: the [debugging aid modifier characters](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Modifier_Characters). By inserting `%`, `#`, `!`, or `*` before an object (including aggregate objects), you can control how it renders in relation to the whole file; this makes it possible to do "binary search" type operations to figure out where the object you're seeing is.

Comment: I know. The problem is that I have apparently spread this out over the file, so would be tedious.

Comment: It can be tedious, but those characters are the tools.  I agree that a "point to it and the code opens" feature would be great, but as yet it does not exist.